# Electron — Open native dialog window from renderer

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to open a simple file browser window in Electron. This snippet, straight from the [docs:](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog/)

```
const { dialog } = require('electron')
console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] }))
```

doesn't work, and causes:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'showOpenDialog')`

I know there are multiple threads about this, but none of the solutions suggested there seem to work. Adding `enableRemoteModule: true` to the `BrowserWindow` definition certainly doesn't. It also doesn't seem to matter if I add `.remote` or `.remote.dialog` to the `require()` line.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed Electron into the project in which this code exists?

Comment: Now I run "npm i electron" just to be sure, but it didn't help.

Comment: `dialog` is an API available to the main process only hence why the error.

Comment: Yes, I figured this out. I'm now trying to access it in the preloader, to pass it on with contextBridge, and it's still undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dialog` API is available to the main process only.

You need to have your renderer process asking the main process to open a dialog on its behalf via an IPC channel. This can be done by having your preload script expose an API.

**main.js**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow, dialog, ipcMain} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  });
  win.loadFile('renderer.html');
  ipcMain.on('hey-open-my-dialog-now', () => {
    dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections']})
  });
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const {ipcRenderer, contextBridge} = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('MY_APP_NAMESPACE', {
  openDialog() {
    ipcRenderer.send('hey-open-my-dialog-now');
  }
});
```

**renderer.html**

```html
<body>
  <button>Ask main process to open a dialog</button>
  <script>
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
      MY_APP_NAMESPACE.openDialog();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Then run with:

```
$ npx electron main.js
```

Comment: Thank you! It's invoke() not send(), but the result works!

Comment: Both works. Which one you should use pretty much depends on your use case. Glad it helped.